# data manipulation in nested python dictionary

Tags: python, django

I have the list of dictionaries which was obtained from previous function:

```
[{'chapter1': [{'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '1'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '2'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '3'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 50.0, 'seq_no': '4'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 0.0, 'seq_no': '5'}]}],
[{'chapter2': [{'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '1'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '2'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '3'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 50.0, 'seq_no': '4'}, {'attended_right_percentage': 0.0, 'seq_no': '5'}]}]
```

Now i want to fetch the data i.e; average of `attended_right_percentage` for each chapter.

Comment: are you getting this data from queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would be better if all your chapters are on one list, like this:

```
chapters_list = [
    {'chapter1': [
        {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '1'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '2'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '3'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 50.0, 'seq_no': '4'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 0.0, 'seq_no': '5'}
    ]},
    {'chapter2': [
        {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '1'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '2'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 100.0, 'seq_no': '3'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 50.0, 'seq_no': '4'},
        {'attended_right_percentage': 0.0, 'seq_no': '5'}
    ]}
]
```

Then you can solve your task like this:

```
chapters_stats = dict()

for chapter in chapters_list:
    for chapter_title, stats_list in chapter.items():
        calculated_amount = 0
        calculated_sum = 0
        for stat_dct in stats_list:
            for key, value in stat_dct.items():
                if key == 'attended_right_percentage':
                    calculated_sum += value
                    calculated_amount += 1
        chapters_stats[chapter_title] = calculated_sum / calculated_amount

print(chapters_stats)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is little bit odd (I've modified this a bit).

```
data = [
        {
            "chapter1": [
                {
                    "seq_no": "1",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 100.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "2",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 100.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "3",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 100.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "4",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 50.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "5",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 0.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "chapter2": [
                {
                    "seq_no": "1",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 100.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "2",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 100.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "3",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 100.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "4",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 50.0
                },
                {
                    "seq_no": "5",
                    "attended_right_percentage": 0.0
                }
            ]
        }
]

def mean(nums):
    return sum(nums) / float(len(nums))

for chapter in data:
    for name, sequence in chapter.items():
        print(mean([seq['attended_right_percentage'] for seq in sequence]))
```

But TBH with you - you shouldn't be posting question like that. It is an elementary python knowledge.